# Keep track of which parts of the HDD are being accessed?

Tags: linux, logging, hard-drive

I'm diagnosing a weird issue and I need to know which sectors of my hard drive are being read and when. Is there a way to make kernel log each access of a block device and ideally, report the offset over UDP?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1065537/find-processes-generating-large-io-load-on-a-specific-drive/1065577#1065577 the answer applies to your case too (then about UDP, try socat)

Comment: @A.B thanks for the link!